# onclick refresh but not from cache?

Tags: javascript

I have this button to refresh the page

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Reload Page" 
              onClick="window.location.href = window.location.pathname;">';
```

What is the easiest way to make sure that the page is read not from cache? To use `Math.random()` Something like

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Reload Page"  
 onClick="window.location.href = window.location.pathname&\'?t=\'&Math.random();">';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reload from server use:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

Info: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/reload.html

Comment: if I use this I get `404 - Not Found`

Comment: and this in an error log `(connections.c.1710) SSL (error): 5 -1 32 Broken pipe`

Comment: Is it reloading to the same location? Does a regular window.location.reload() work?

Comment: it doesn't work as expected :-( if I modify my php file, save and then hit the button. I will not see the change after the first reload ...

Comment: @iivel: I did some testing and if I edit the php file by text editor "Bluefish" the refresh button doesn't work as desired but if I edit the same file via 'joe' the page is `always` refreshed correctly using the code you provided. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Math.random() will work, so will (new Date()).getTime() also works.

Comment: what would be the syntax for that? Can I use `window.location.pathname` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way of doing this is via server side, by setting the header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067) article for more details.

Comment: sometimes I have to click 10x to see the change I made in my .php file after I added `META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">`

Answer (score 0):

instead of javascript why not link directly

```
<?php
echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "&=" . time() . "'>Reload Page</a>";
?>
```

instead?

Edit :: As i note I only suggest this because you included the sample php within your original post.

Comment: What if I made my URL `index.php/" onclick="alert('xss')` ?